# Not able to send a zip file through javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an attachment containing a zip file through javamail. However, while sending it throws an exception as

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 552-5.7.0 This message was blocked because its content presents a potential 552-5.7.0 security issue.

I added MIME content type as `application/zip` but facing

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
 nested exception is:
 javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type 
 application/zip at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1167)
```

Below is my code snippet:

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "application/zip");
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
File srcFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/Reports/");
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(srcFile.getPath()+"/Report.zip");
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName("Report.zip");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);
```

When I remove the .zip extension it works fine but not with .zip.

Comment: What happens when? The first error seems to suggest that your mail server doesn't like zip-attachments, the second error is totally different and would happen before the email is handed over to the server. Which is it?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel :All errors come at `Transport.send(message);`.

Comment: But you should get one or the other. Not both. Please describe carefully when you get one error and when the other.

Comment: @Mark Rottevee : You are right. I am not getting both the errors same time. i got `SMTPSendFailedException` when using `text/html` while defining the content type. But if i add the content type `application/zip` i get the `no object DCH for MIME type 
 application/zip`. i changed the content type thinking MIME TYPE for zip.

Comment: Please show your full code. Also your reuse of variables makes it hard to follow your logic. For example why are you using `messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "application/zip");`, when - I presume - `message` is not the attachment.

Comment: Code added by Bill Shannon below will work  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43398833/7751463

Answer (score 1):

Your code is adding the attachment twice, which I'm sure is not what you want.  Replace your code with this:

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String srcFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Reports/Report.zip";
messageBodyPart.attachFile(srcFile, "application/zip", "base64");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: :I changed my code as per your input. However, `messageBodyPart.attachFile(srcFile, "application/zip", "base64");` is taking one parameter only in my code. And after execution it is still showing  `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 552-5.7.0 This message was blocked because its content presents a potential 552-5.7.0 security issue` at `transport.send(message)`

Comment: There are multiple attachFile methods.  The one with only one parameter will choose the MIME type and encoding for you.  If you want to force the MIME type to be application/zip, you need the version with three parameters.  And of course none of this is going to get around the security restrictions of your email service that's preventing you from sending zip files.  For that you need to talk to your email service provider, or send your data some way other than an attached zip file.